# How to add USGS DRG WMS to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

Is there a WMS server, which I can be add to QGIS, that displays USGS Digital Raster Graphics (DRGs)?  If so please explain how?

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same question and I've found the answer:

http://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgiswms

Note that the author made an error, by pointing to the line "Contours - Small Scale".  This is incorrect.  For DRGs you should actually click on the link on the line labelled "Scanned Topo Maps".

FYI, I've had mixed results displaying the 24K DRGs.  Sometimes they don't display unless I've also loaded the 250K and 100K layers.  But I'm new to QGIS, so the problem might be my inexperience.  I hope this helps!